# Mysql using CHAR or BLOB to store UTF-8 string with known byte size limit

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mariadb, blob, innodb

I have UTF-8 strings I want to store in a Mysql/MariaDB column. I can't use VARCHAR because of the limit on the number of characters per column. I am far over that limit.

I know the maximum number of bytes to contain the largest UTF-8 string I have. Reading the docs it appears using CHAR or TEXT will allocate 3 bytes (or 4 for UTF8MB4) per char. Since I know the real size would it work if I stored the string in a BLOB? Will this work at all? Are there any known issues with this approach?

I'm using MariaDB with InnoDB and UTF8MB4.

Comment: I am not sure if we can search within BLOB. Won't you need to use `where` condition on this field ever ?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that using a BLOB means I will give up the ability to use  `where` to check the UTF-8 contents.  It would be better to find a non BLOB solution. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Isn't that what the TEXT types are intended for? Why use BLOB?

Answer (score 0):

`MEDIUMTEXT` can handle 16 million *bytes* (at least 4 million utf8mb4 _characters).  Will that suffice?

`MEDIUMBLOB` can also handle 16 million bytes.

Use variants on `CHAR` and `TEXT` for *characters*.  This gives you checking of encoding, comparisons, sorting, etc.  Use variants on `BINARY` and `BLOB` for bytes that you don't need to manipulate -- such as images.

Consider using a `FULLTEXT` index for efficiently searching for specific *words* in a `TEXT` column.  `LIKE`, `MID()`, etc also work with large `TEXT` columns, but not necessarily efficiently.

Your Question is imprecise on what you are trying to do.  If I have not given you enough clues, please elaborate on your data and querying requirements.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Using a BLOB or BINARY is just a bad idea. For the size of the strings I have  TEXT will be large enough for all cases. I came to this conclusion after doing more reading and looking at examples. Your response verified what I had learned. Thanks.